# Check if a variable is in the string constant pool

Tags: java, string, constants, pool

In Java when we use literal string when creating a string object, I know that a new object is created in SCP (string constant pool).

Is there a way to check if a variable is in the SCP or in the heap?

Comment: *i know that a new object is created in SCP*: well, no. But seriously, why do you care? It's an implementation detail. You shouldn't care about that.

Comment: It’s not possible to find out, even through reflection because String’s `intern()` method is `native`.

Comment: `if (a != a.intern())` then it ***wasn't*** in the string constant pool. But the `a.intern()` adds it, so afterward it is in the constant pool.

Comment: (The dupe question chosen did not answer the questions asked here.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the correct term is the "string pool", not the "string constant pool"; see [String pool - do String always exist in constant pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414169/string-pool-do-string-always-exist-in-constant-pool/57414694#57414694)

Secondly, you are not checking a variable.  You are checking the string that some variable contains / refers to.  (A variable that contains a reference to the string, cannot be be "in the SCP".  The variable is either on the stack, in the heap (not SCP), or in metaspace.)

> Is there a way to check if a variable is in SCP or in heap ?

1. From Java 7 and later, the string pool is in the (normal) heap.  So your question is moot if we interpret it literally.
2. Prior to Java 7, the way to check if a `String` is in the string pool was to do this

   ```
   if (str == str.intern()) {
       System.out.println("In the string pool");
   }
   ```

   However, this had the problem that if an equivalent `str` was not already in the pool, you would have added a copy of `str` to the pool.
3. From Java 7 onwards, the above test is no longer reliable.  A `str.intern()` no longer needs to copy a string to a separate region to add it the string pool.  Therefore the reference to an intern'd string is *often* identical to the reference to the original (non-interned) string.

   ```
   char[] chars = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'};
   String str = new String(chars);
   String interned = str.intern();
   System.out.println(str == interned);
   ```

   In fact `str == str.intern()` can only detect the case where you have a non-interned string with the same content as a string literal.

> Or at least list all string instances in SCP ?

There is no way to do that.

---

As JB Nizet pointed out, there is really not a lot of point in asking these questions:

- You shouldn't be writing code that depends on whether a string is in the string pool or not.
- If you are concerned about storage to the level where you would contemplate calling `intern` for yourself, it is better to make use of the opportunistic string compaction mechanism provided by Java 9+ garbage collectors.