# In Java literal strings only stored in the string constant pool?

Tags: java, string

Are literal strings only stored in the string constant pool? Isn't it stored in the constant pool? Or are both stored?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit - what exaclty confused you? Perhaps you could quote some documentation you read, or explain with some example?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777131/java-string-intern-and-literal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strings are objects in Java, so why don't we use 'new' to create them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414169/string-pool-do-string-always-exist-in-constant-pool      I read in this post he says In the string pool and constant pool that's why i have some questions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414169/string-pool-do-string-always-exist-in-constant-pool  and I see i this post says like this The constant pool is a table of structures which represents various, class and interface names, field names, string constants and other constants that are referred to within the ClassFile structure and its substructures.

Comment: 1. The question in your title and first sentence is ambiguous. 2. What is 'it'? 3. What are 'both'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630087/in-java-literal-strings-only-stored-in-the-string-constant-pool#comment114275751_64630087), you added a link to question "[String pool - do String always exist in constant pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57414169/5221149)". Since you apparently didn't understand the beginning of the answer, let me recap:

- The **constant pool** is part of a `.class` file.
- The **string pool** is part of the JVM's memory for storing *interned* strings.

There is no *"string constant pool"* anywhere.

String *literals* are stored in the `.class` file in the **constant pool** part of the file. When a `.class` file is loaded into memory, the string literals are loaded into *interned* strings, and hence end up being stored in the **string pool**.

So, to answer the question: String literals are store in *both* the **constant pool** (on disk) and in the **string pool** (in memory).